# onActivityResult no esta funcionando y no puedo resolverlo

Tags: java, android

este es mi codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tafel);

        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"button works!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, TafelActivity.class);

                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * is not calling this method
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String fromTafel = data.getStringExtra("result");

                Log.v("resultado",fromTafel);
                TextView resultaat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultaat);

                resultaat.setText(fromTafel);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

en la segunda actividad esta

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent =  new Intent(TafelActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("result",tafel.toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

eso funciona bastante bien pero no se si la intent esta funcionando

Comment: intenta poner `finish();` despues de setResult() para pasar a la primera actividad.

Comment: El problema es que estas iniciando el activity en el contexto de la subclase que implementa el listener. Intenta con MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0); en el onClick.

Answer (score 0):

El código en tu segunda actividad no es correcto, debes escribir lo siguiente:

**En la segunda actividad**

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     switch (item.getItemId()) {

         case android.R.id.home:
             Intent intent =  new Intent();
             intent.putExtra("result",tafel.toString());
             setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
             finish();

         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```